# How to disable specific tests for mvn package command?

Tags: maven, unit-testing, testing, configuration, pom.xml

I have integration tests in the package:

```
my.campaign.ololo.controller.external
```

I want to not run that tests during `mvn clean package`

So I wrote following in my `pom.xml`

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.21.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>my.campaign.ololo.controller.external</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Then I execute `mvn clean package`

and see in logs following:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 10, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

So looks like tests were execute because I don't have another tests in the project now.

How can I disable test while executing command `mvn package`, `mvn install` and so on?

### P.S.

I understand that maven has fixed build phase order and test phase executes before package.

Comment: Why don't you like to execute the test? What is the real problem with those tests?

Comment: @khmarbaise Do you want to explain that I don't have to disable tests? It is environment deployment configuration problem

Comment: First I want to understand why you like to disable tests? Which is usually a bad idea...

Comment: @khmarbaise It is environment deployment configuration problem

Comment: So this means those test/tests are integration test which means they should be named accordingly the schemas which are defined. `*Test.java` (Unit Test) and `*IT.java` integration tests. furthermore IT's should be run by maven-failsafe-plugin (use a profile to deactivate running the IT's) furthermore have a deployment within a Maven build sounds simply wrong to me....

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks I got that I wanted